# Checked Event of checkbox column of DevExpress's DataGrid control in wpf

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I want to perform some tasks on Checked Event of checkbox column of DevExpress's DataGrid control in wpf.

Comment: Where is the question ? Have you tried something ? Or is this just an information for the world ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To track when the value of corresponding boolean colums is changed i suggest you handle the [TabbedView.CellValueChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_CellValueChangedtopic) event:

```
((TableView)gridControl.View).CellValueChanged += MainWindow_CellValueChanged
//...
void MainWindow_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "BooleanProp") { 
        // do something
    }
}
```

To track Checked/Unchecked event directly on cell editor you can use the following approach:

```
((TableView)gridControl.View).ShownEditor += TableView_ShownEditor;
((TableView)gridControl.View).HiddenEditor += TableView_HiddenEditor;
//...

void TableView_ShownEditor(object sender, EditorEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "BooleanProp") {
        ((DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit)e.Editor).Checked += BooleanPropCheckEdit_Checked;
        ((DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit)e.Editor).Unchecked += BooleanPropCheckEdit_Unchecked;
    }
}
void TableView_HiddenEditor(object sender, EditorEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "BooleanProp") {
        ((DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit)e.Editor).Checked -= BooleanPropCheckEdit_Checked;
        ((DevExpress.Xpf.Editors.CheckEdit)e.Editor).Unchecked -= BooleanPropCheckEdit_Unchecked;
    }
}
void BooleanPropCheckEdit_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // do something
}
void BooleanPropCheckEdit_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // do something
}
```